# Function to Create Y-Values

Tags: r

I was hoping someone might be able to help me make sense of a homework question. I am not looking for a solution, mind you, just wondering if anyone would be able to explain the question a bit more simply for me, as I am new to data analysis and enrolled in an R class which had no prerequisites, but feel a bit lost with some of the language. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

So, the first part of the question was to create an array and fill it with random numeric data, which I did here:

```
question <- array( 1:1000, dim= c(25,4,1000))
colnames(question)<- c('x1','x2','x3','x4')
```

Now, the second part asks me to "write a function to create y-values," which should be a "linear combination" of the four variables. The example given is

```
y = 2 ∗ x1 + 5 ∗ x2 − 3 ∗ x3 + 0.7 ∗ x4 + RandomError.
```

The question adds that the result should be a matrix with dimensions of 25 × 1000. I am not sure what exactly this is asking or how to approach this problem. All I have so far, which I know is very little is

```
apply(question,c(1,3),sum)
function (y){ ...
```

Can anyone offer any guidance or clarification? Thank you so much!

Comment: first thing first: you are not generating **random** numbers in the first part. You are just generating a sequence to 1 from 1000, which is not a random (or more correctly *pseudo-*) number generation.

Comment: In you colnames assignment is a parenthesis missing. What are your definitions of 'RandomError' and 'part1.1'? Which dimension is 'y' supposed to have?

Comment: Cleb - thank you for noticing the parenthesis - I have it in the original code but accidentally left it out in my post. I edited to fix it. Thanks. As for the random vs pseudo-number generation, that is a fair point SabDeM and I appreciate you pointing out the difference. As to Cleb's point about the RandomError, I am not sure how to answer...the question just says it should be some "normally distributed error."

Answer (score 1):

First of all, to make (pseudo)random numbers, you can use the `rnorm` function. That is, if you want to make 1000 random numbers that are normally distributed with mean of 0 and sd of 1, you can do rnorm(1000) (However, your array ends up being length 10000, so maybe you actually want to do rnorm(10000)).

Now, you should have an array `question` with dimensions 25 x 4 x 1000. You want to create a matrix `y` which combines four "slices" in `question` of size 25 x 1000 to create a matrix `y` of size 25 x 1000. You want to write a function `f` that will take all four "slices" of array `question` and combine them into one slice. You also want to incorporate random error, which again can be accomplished with the `rnorm` function.

For a simple example, let's make an array `x` with dimensions(10,2,10)

```
x = array(rnorm(200), dim = c(10,2,10))
```

And now let's write a function `f` that will add the two "slices" of x together.

```
f = function(my_array){
    my_array[,1,] + my_array[,2,]
    }
```

Let's execute the function on our array

```
y = f(x)
dim(y)
```

Hopefully you can expand this basic example to fit your case.